# Flask forms, filter using drop down

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Newbie Attempting to filter returned items based on cascading dropdowns.
Get the following error:
NotImplementedError: Operator 'getitem' is not supported on this expression

Code Below

`class Asset(db.Model):
    """
    asset table
    """
    __tablename_ = 'asset'

```
inv_id = db.Column(db.String(15), primary_key=True)
descript = db.Column(db.String(50))
station = db.Column(db.String(3))
inv_class = db.Column(db.String(10))

@admin.route('/assets', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
    def list_assets():
    form = Form()
    form.station.choices = [(Asset.station) for station in 
    Asset.query.filter_by(inv_class='HOSE').all()]

class Form(FlaskForm):
inv_class = SelectField('inv_class', choices = [])
station = SelectField('station', choices = [])

<body>
    <form method="GET","POST">

        {{ form.inv_class }}
        {{ form.station }}
    </form>
</body>
```

Fist dropdown should filter to inv_class, second by station, then return list of assets that include both.